# How to Print only the exact size of the report in Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, printing, datagridview, crystal-reports, dot-matrix

I want to print the data using the `crystal report` which is generated from the database the report is depend upon the data requested by the user.

It may be of **5 lines** or it may can vary to ***20 to 25 lines*** now while printing in the dot matrix printer.

I have a problem that it prints the data but then it sends out till the end of the page as blank so it creates a problem for the customer to adjust the paper again in the printer

What the changes I should have to make in `crystal report` to make it print only the exact size of the report generated from the `datagrid` view.

I am using TVS 250 star dot matrix printer

Comment: Please stop flagging this for moderator attention. It is not our job to answer your questions like this, and you are wasting our moderation efforts.

Comment: You could try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835212/programmatically-set-custom-paper-size-for-crystal-report) setting

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions here

[Programmatically set Custom Paper Size for Crystal Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835212/programmatically-set-custom-paper-size-for-crystal-report)

also 
when you are printing in TVS 250 star dot matrix printer
 convert the "Crystal Report" to txt file and then print may be easy..