# Programmatically set Custom Paper Size for Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-xi, page-size

I have created custom paper Size "SUPP 15 x 14" in `Setting - Printers - File - Server Properties.` Now I’m trying to set custom Paper Size for Crystal Report using VB.net 2005.

When I run report from VB.net, the Crystal report viewer shows the correct preview for custom paper size but when I give print command it prints with the default printer paper size. (e.g Letter)

Here's the code I'm using to print:

```
Public Sub ...
    '...
    Dim ObjCrReport as new ReportDocument
    '...
    ObjCrReport.SetDataSource(ObjPrintDataSet.Tables("PrintData"))
    SetReportPageSize("SUPP 15 x 14", 1)
    '...
End Sub

Private Sub BtnPrintDoc_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnPrintDoc.Click
    Try
        'Print command
        ObjCrReport.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub SetReportPageSize(ByVal mPaperSize As String, ByVal PaperOrientation As Integer)
    Try
        Dim ObjPrinterSetting As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings
        Dim PkSize As New System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize
        ObjPrinterSetting.PrinterName = "Epson FX1170"
        For i As Integer = 0 To ObjPrinterSetting.PaperSizes.Count - 1
            If ObjPrinterSetting.PaperSizes.Item(i).PaperName = mPaperSize.Trim Then
                PkSize = ObjPrinterSetting.PaperSizes.Item(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If PkSize IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim myAppPrintOptions As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.PrintOptions = ObjCrReport.PrintOptions
            myAppPrintOptions.PrinterName = "Epson FX1170"
            myAppPrintOptions.PaperSize = CType(PkSize.RawKind, CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize)
            ObjCrReport.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = IIf(PaperOrientation = 1, _
                                    CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperOrientation.Portrait, _
                                    CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperOrientation.Landscape)
        End If
        PkSize = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

If I use `myAppPrintOptions.PaperSize = PaperSize.PaperLegal`, then Print Preview & Printing appear correct, but I want to set custom paper size which is not showing in the `PaperSize` class.

What’s wrong with above code? Why is it printing Letter Size where Crystal report preview otherwise shows custom paper in the size preview? Is there a better way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: no one have any answer ? I have the exact same problem here at work.

Comment: It could be that Printer is set to _"Letter Size"_ by default. still has no answer it's now 2016

Answer (score 3):

This Method works with an **Epson LX-300+ ii Dot-Matrix Printer** and later models

If you are using a Printer especially for **Printing Receipts**
here are the steps on how to set your printer for desired paper size

First Set up Printer to be used:
Go to **Devices and Printers**
in Printers select the Printer you are going to use and click - right click **Printer Properties**
Click **Preferences...** Button. Under **Main** Tab - Change **Document Size** to **User Defined**
a new New Window will appear. 
in Paper Size Name specify the name (i.e. OR Paper)
and change paper width and height as desired
Click **Save** then **OK**

[image]
then set your printer by Pressing right click then **set as Default Printer**

Add these line of code for your printing. You can still use parameters and datasets.

```
Dim c As Integer
    Dim doctoprint As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument()
    doctoprint.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "EPSON L1300 Series"
    Dim rawKind As Integer
    For c = 0 To doctoprint.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count - 1
        If doctoprint.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes(c).PaperName = "OR Receipts" Then
            rawKind = CInt(doctoprint.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes(c).GetType().GetField("kind", Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or 

Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(doctoprint.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes(c)))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Report1.PrintOptions.PaperSize = CType(rawKind, CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize)
    frmPreview.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report1
    Report1.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do as this

```
var rep = new YursCrystalReport();
var printerSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
var pSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings(printerSettings); 
pSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("newsize", 3000, 3000);//custom size  hundredths (100=1 inch)
pSettings.Margins = new System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
rep.PrintOptions.DissociatePageSizeAndPrinterPaperSize = true;
rep.PrintOptions.CopyFrom(printerSettings, pSettings);
```