# Set Up Half Sheet Printing - Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

I'm trying to set up a print on an `EPSON LX-300 + II ESC/P` for half sheet on a `Crystal Report`. I can even set the paper size in the report and printer, but the problem is that it is printing in the landscape orientation as in the image below.

[image: Wrong Orientation]

I have tried several configurations like those of the links below and it did not solved.

[Programmatically set Custom Paper Size for Crystal Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835212/programmatically-set-custom-paper-size-for-crystal-report)

[Crystal Report custom page/paper size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31103918)

I'm using Crystal Report runtime engine version `13.0.15`, Crystal report for Visual Studio version `13.0.17` and Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Are you sure the printer orientation is portrait in the rpt file? (right click report, design, printer setup)

Comment: Yes I'm sure, for test, I even tried the two orientations